# Image View in ListView Item

Tags: android, listview

I have a listView.  Each row/item of ListView contains 2 Views  a  **TextView** and a **ImageView**.  I want  that only **ImageView can be focussable and  clickable and textView should not be focusable and clickable**.

Eachrow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewEachBlockedKeyword"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Keyword"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewBlockKeywordDelete"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3.1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"


    android:src="@drawable/delete" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How to do this ?
Thanks

Comment: have u tried setting the clickable property in the textview to be false?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewEachBlockedKeyword"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Keyword"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewBlockKeywordDelete"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3.1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/delete"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 android:focusable="false"
   android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
   android:clickable="false"
```

add this to your textview tag

Answer (score 0):

try below code just change imageview into imagebutton

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewEachBlockedKeyword"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Keyword"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageViewBlockKeywordDelete"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3.1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/delete" />

</LinearLayout>
```